# Dovecot - imap-login SSL_accept() failed

Tags: email, postfix, ssl, mail, dovecot

today i configured Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL from tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

Actual dovecot settings:

```
root@cermofi-lab:~# dovecot -n
# 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.16 (09c29328)
# OS: Linux 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ext4
# Hostname: cermofi-lab
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/cermofi.cz/fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

Actual Postfix settings:

```
root@cermofi-lab:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = cermofi.cz
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/cermofi.cz/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/cermofi.cz/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Sending email via **SMTP (telnet localhost 25)** is sucessful. But when i try to send it via TLS (command starttls in telnet returning "Connection closed by foreign host.") it fails. Also when I try to connect to dovecot (telnet localhost 993) I got same error message as on TLS.

Mail.err is empty.
Mail.log:

```
Jan 30 17:29:45 cermofi-lab dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number, session=<kkgxRSwQwsx/AAAB>
```

and

```
Jan 30 17:37:05 cermofi-lab postfix/smtpd[41027]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
Jan 30 17:37:05 cermofi-lab postfix/smtpd[41027]: lost connection after STARTTLS from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

My certificates seems OK:
(output of openssl s_client -showcerts -connect cermofi.cz:993 -servername cermofi.cz)

```
    Start Time: 1706632917
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
```

Any ideas why is it failing on TLS?
Thanks.

Comment: *"But when i try to send it via TLS (command starttls in telnet returning "Connection closed by foreign host.")"* - what exactly are you doing? You cannot simply enter "starttls" in telnet and expect magic to happen. You have to actually do a TLS handshake after that. Try to use instead `openssl s_client -connect localhost:25 -starttls smtp`.. Similar you cannot simply telnet to port 993 for imap - instead TLS is expected here. The kind of error you see is very common if TLS is expected but not provided, like when using telnet.